# How can I clear a specific Request.Form value in Classic ASP or jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I have Classic ASP page that updates a MS SQL Table with a very long Base64 Value from a form element, but on the same page I have a function that use all form elements (except this) and translates them to values in an e-mail, problem is that the specific base64 form element breaks this operation, and I therefor needs to clear this value or simply set a different to the `Request.Form("ProfilePicture")`since I am not able to sort this element out from being used.

I have been looking through the documentation of ASP Classic, but is not able to find a function that can do just this, the closest I have come is a function that clears all form elements, which is in my case not an option since the other form values are important to the next function.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue, preferable in ASP Classic, or maybe using jQuery?

***As requested some code (Only key elements of the form submit)***

**Main form :**

```html
<form id="ConFirmSolvedForm" name="ConFirmSolvedForm" method="post" class="demo-form">

<input type="file" class="inputfile inputfile-4" accept="image/jpeg"> //This is the file choosen, but I only use this for getting the Base64 String

<input type="hidden" name="ProfilePicture" id="srcAttribute" value="" width="100%" /> //This contains Base64 string

<button type="submit" formaction="insert_confirm_tasks_solved.asp" id="UploadPrifileButton" class="next btn btn-secondary shadow-custom">Save</button>
```

**(Part of) insert_confirm_tasks_solved.asp:**

```html
subject = request.form("subject_WhoIsWho")
template = request.form("template_WhoIsWho")
    
Set adoStream = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
adoStream.Type = 2
adoStream.Open
adoStream.Charset = "UTF-8"
adoStream.LoadFromFile server.mappath("" & template & "")
template = adoStream.ReadText(-1)
adoStream.Close
Set adoStream = Nothing
getTextFromFile = template
    
set msg = server.createobject("CDO.Message")
msg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
msg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "" & objSettings("SMTPServer") & ""
msg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = objSettings("SMTPPort")
msg.Configuration.Fields.Update
msg.subject = subject
msg.BodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
msg.to = objSettings("WhoISEmail")
msg.from = """" & objSettings("MailFromName") & """ <" & objSettings("MailFromEmail") & ">"
msg.Sender = """" & objSettings("MailFromName") & """ <" & objSettings("MailFromEmail") & ">"

if len(cc) > 0 then msg.cc = cc
if len(bcc) > 0 then msg.bcc = bcc

body = template

body = replace(body, "[$PortraitAdminName$]", "" & Request.Form("PortraitAdminName") & "")

body = replace(body, "[$LinkToConfirmSolved$]", "index.asp?LoadSpecificPage=confirm_tasks_solved.asp&RoleType=WhoIsWho&id=" & Request.Form("ID") & "")

body = replace(body, "[$LinkToNewEmploy$]", "login.asp?LoadSpecificPage=flow.asp&ShowPagePart=FlowNotDone&GetSpecificUserOnFlow=yes&UserIDOnFlow=" & Request.Form("id") & "")

for each item in request.form
    body = replace(body, "[$" & item & "$]", replace(request.form(item),vbcrlf,"<br>"))
next


rx.pattern = "\[\$.*\$\]"
rx.global = true
body = rx.replace(body, "")

msg.htmlbody = body

msg.send

set msg = nothing
```

**Error I get:**

`Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required: ''

/insert_confirm_tasks_solved.asp, line 670`

Line 670 is : `rx.pattern = "\[\$.*\$\]"`

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your full code, but if you're trying to encode images as Base64 and post them, you'll probably get some form of overflow error due to the Query String length. A solution may be to max out the acceptable Query String length: `web.config > system.web` `<httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536"/>`

Alternatively, you could prevent the image being encoded with Base64 client side (jQuery) and treat them as binary post... but with pure classic ASP that has it's own issues (well documented).

Comment: If you're just wanting to use jQuery to emit a form value during an aJax post, that should be easy enough without having to worry about Classic ASP server side..

Comment: @Adam .. I am not using Ajax to post the data from the form,only ASP .. I only thought that clearing it using jQuery could be a backup plan :-)

Comment: It might be helpful if you include some sample code. Because it's a bit unclear what the problem / ASP error is.

Comment: My spider-sense tells me your form has "enctype='multipart/form-data'" :)

Comment: @Adam .. Added code as asked to my post

Comment: @Flakes .. I do not use `enctype='multipart/form-data` in my form :-)

Comment: I was wrong, I am not spider man. :(

Comment: For the current error, `rx`  should be initialized before using it. `Dim rx : Set rx = New RegExp`. See: [RegExp Object](https://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/vbscript/objects-regexp.html)

Comment: @Flakes .. Spot on! .. This is my fault.., `Dim rx : Set rx = New RegExp` was actually already set in line 419, but was not used because of an `IF`  .. I have moved it outside this, and now it runs as it should .. thank you for being "awake" when I was not :-) .. if you submit this as an answer I will give you the credit.

Comment: Glad to help. Its just one of those things. Next time, please post code with your question so that people do not have to make guesses. :)

Comment: @Flakes .. Will do ;-)